# Juint 5 cannot resolve parameter to method

Tags: java, junit5

I have a simple test for a web endpoint and I am testing a json schema using restAssured. I keep getting:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [java.lang.String arg0] in method [void People.init(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)].
```

I've read the JUnit 5 manual and I really don't understand this error. 
As far as I can see there is nothing wrong with the input strings to the `init` method. I really don't get this error. Could someone please explain to me what's causing this error and how to get around it in this context?

```
import Utils;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.get;
import static io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath;

@DisplayName(value = "Tests endpoint")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:resources")

class People {

private String PEOPLE_QUERY = "PeopleQStar.json";
private String host = "http://dev-dev/";
private String endPoint = "people";

Utils utils = new Utils();

@BeforeAll
void init(String host, String endPoint)
{
    utils.setHostAndPath(host, endPoint);
    utils.setCommonSettings();
}

@AfterAll
void cleanUp()
{
    utils.tearDown();
}

@Order(1)
@DisplayName("Check if endpoint is up")
@Test
void initialComCheck()
{
    get().then().statusCode(200);
}

@Order(2)
@Test
public void givenUrl_whenJsonResponseConformsToSchema_thenCorrect() {

    get("?q=*").then().assertThat()
            .body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath(PEOPLE_QUERY));
}
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to parameterize `init()`?

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dependency-injection

Comment: @ArhoHuttunen I really don't need to but I will do this for a many endpoints. Could you explain what is going on? I don't think I fully understand the doc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider following changes to your code:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterContext;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolver;
//... other imports and annotations
@ExtendWith(CustomParameterResolver.class) // your custom parameter resolver, see below
class People {

//...

  @BeforeAll
  void init(Server server) // custom stub for storage of your params
  {
    utils.setHostAndPath(server.getHost(), server.getEndpoint());
    utils.setCommonSettings();
  }

  // other methods as it is
}

  static class Server {
    private String host = "http://dev-dev/";
    private String endpoint = "people";

    public String getHost() {
      return host;
    }

    public String getEndpoint() {
      return endpoint;
    }
  }

  static class CustomParameterResolver implements ParameterResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext,
        ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
      return (parameterContext.getParameter().getType() == Server.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext,
        ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
      return new Server();
    }
  }
```

That should help to solve your issue. Main problem in your case is `@BeforeAll` method default signature(which is without parameters). That is why you getting an exception( because it's not aware of any custom parameters you trying to pass). To solve this JUnit 5 API allows you to define custom `ParameterResolver` and subsequently apply it with `@ExtendsWith`

I've introduced *stub object* for simplification, but I'm sure that there is an option to solve this with 2 `String` parameters

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Apologies for the delay in my response. I simply forgot :-(

Comment: It's fine. Hope that helped!)

Comment: it helped a lot :-)